# Python package version sastisfied, but does not appear

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, seaborn, version

When I run the command:

```
sudo pip3 install seaborn==0.11.1
```

I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: seaborn==0.11.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (0.11.1)
```

However, when I check the version in python3 I get:

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import seaborn as sns
>>> sns.__version__
'0.10.1'
```

How can I fix this, and what is it I don't understand about python packages?

Edit:
removing sudo from the install command fixed the issue, thank you very much!

While we're on the topic: why does installing with `sudo apt install python3-<package>` also make   the package available for `user`, while `sudo pip3 install <package>` does not?

Comment: You have installed the package as root, but are your running python as root or as user?

You can try to install the package as user with: `pip3 install seaborn==0.11.1 --user` or run python as root with `sudo python3`

Comment: removing sudo from the install command fixed the issue, thank you very much! 
While we're on the topic: why does installing with `sudo apt install python3-<package>` also make   the package available for `user`, while `sudo pip3 install <package>` does not?

Comment: If your question is solved, it is better to add it as an answer rather than a comment, regarding your question does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431780/apt-get-install-vs-pip-install#:~:text=pip%20is%20used%20to%20download,which%20are%20hosted%20by%20Canonical.) help? It is always worth googling before asking here.

Comment: `apt` install for all the users because they are not installed in a particular user's home folder but in the usr folder. Each user will have their own file in their account to save there preferences and data except any user logged in as a guest, as their data is deleted on logging out. The problem that pip3 don't install for all the available users is probably related to the umask, try uninstall the package `pip3 uninstall seaborn`, change umask `cd ~ && umask 022`, install again as root `sudo pip3 install seaborn==0.11.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are installing the package as root, but running python3 as user.

Install the package as user: `pip3 install seaborn==0.11.1 --user` and run `python3` as user.

Install the package as root: `pip3 install seaborn==0.11.1` and run `sudo python3` as root.

About your second question in the comment

> why does installing with sudo apt install python3- also make
> the package available for user, while sudo pip3 install  does
> not?

`apt` install for all the users because they are not installed in a particular user's home folder but in the usr folder. Each user will have their own file in their account to save there preferences and data except any user logged in as a guest, as their data is deleted on logging out.

The problem that `pip3` don't install for all the available users is probably related to the `umask`, try uninstall the package `pip3 uninstall seaborn`, change umask `cd ~ && umask 022`, install again as root `sudo pip3 install seaborn==0.11.1`

`umask` is a command to set the default access rights for files / directories, you can read more [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html)